# Why does MinMaxScaler fail with integers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

This looks handy for pre-fixing data:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler scaler =  MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaler.fit_transform([[x] for x in [1,2,3]]) # gives [0, 0, 0]
```

and it gives all zeros, no errors or warnings!? Changing to 1.0,2.0,3.0 makes it output the expected 0, .5, 1 scaled values.

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using? I'm on 0.19.1 and its correctly output for both types/

Comment: 0.14.1 from the Ubuntu 14.04 repo

Comment: are you using python 2?  in py2, ints default to int division and floats default to float division  py2, `3/2` and `3//2` both return `1` and `3.0/2` returns `1.5`  but in py3, only `3//2` returns `1` and `3/2` gets cast as floats and returns `1.5`

Comment: @e.s. No change even when I do `from __future__ import division`

Comment: I get [0, 0.5, 1] both in Python2 and Python3 for your code.